# Can't display all item if order by field nama

Tags: codeigniter

I have model code function in Codeigniter like below, if me sort order by RAND() can display all item but if order by field name like part_no can't display all item, in next page same display with page 1.

**Model**

```
function listProductPerCategory($id, $limit, $start){
    $this->db->select('
        category.id, category.category, product.id, product.id_category,
        product.name, product.picture, product.description, product.permalink, product.part_no
    ');

    $this->db->join('category', 'product.id_category = category.id');
    $this->db->where('product.id_category', $id);
    $this->db->order_by('product.part_no');
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get($this->tableProduct);

    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
function listcategory($page = NULL) {
    $id = $this->input->get('list');
    $data['categoryHead'] = $this->M_home->listCategory();
    $this->load->view('frontend/template/header', $data);
    $data['productsLast'] = $this->M_home->listProductLast();
    $data['productsLast2'] = $this->M_home->listProductLast2();
    $data['category'] = $this->M_home->listCategory();

    //paging
    $config['base_url']         = base_url('categoryproduct'.'?'.http_build_query($_GET));
    $config['total_rows']       = $this->M_home->listProductPerCategory_num_rows($id);
    $config['per_page']         = $per_page = 12;
    $config['uri_segment']      = 2;
    $config['first_link']       = 'First';
    $config['last_link']        = 'Last';
    $config['next_link']        = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link']        = 'Prev';
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    //end paging

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['paging'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

    $data['listCategory'] = $this->M_home->listProductPerCategory($id, $per_page, $page);
    $this->load->view('frontend/category', $data);

    $this->load->view('frontend/template/footer');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have understand that 
 In SQL LIMIT, start is starting number of record not PAGE.

But from what you passing to listProductPerCategory is page number 
So from page 1 to page 2 it is only one record move on next page not 12 records.

So you need to fix in function listProductPerCategory  (dont forget to change variable name which may you confuse yourself , change $start -> $page)

So you should get this as below

```
function listProductPerCategory($id, $limit, $page){

if($page < 1){
  $page = 1;
}

if($page > 1){
  $start =  $limit * $page;
}else{
  $start = 0;
}



        $this->db->select('
            category.id, category.category, product.id, product.id_category,
            product.name, product.picture, product.description, product.permalink, product.part_no
        ');
        $this->db->join('category', 'product.id_category = category.id');
        $this->db->where('product.id_category', $id);
        $this->db->order_by('product.part_no');
        $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tableProduct);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller -

Try this -

```
function listcategory($page = 0){
    $id = $this->input->get('list');
    $data['categoryHead'] = $this->M_home->listCategory();
    $this->load->view('frontend/template/header', $data);
    $data['productsLast'] = $this->M_home->listProductLast();
    $data['productsLast2'] = $this->M_home->listProductLast2();
    $data['category'] = $this->M_home->listCategory();
    //paging
    $config['base_url']         = base_url('categoryproduct'.'?'.http_build_query($_GET));
    $config['total_rows']       = $this->M_home->listProductPerCategory_num_rows($id);
    $config['per_page']         = $per_page = 12;
    $config['num_links'] = 2;
    $config['uri_segment']      = 3;
    $config['first_link']       = 'First';
    $config['last_link']        = 'Last';
    $config['next_link']        = 'Next';
    $config['prev_link']        = 'Prev';
    $config['page_query_string'] = TRUE;
    //end paging
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['paging'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['page'] = $page;
//  $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;
    $data['listCategory'] = $this->M_home->listProductPerCategory($id, $per_page, $page);
    $this->load->view('frontend/category', $data);
    $this->load->view('frontend/template/footer');
```

Order by condition is wrong in your model.

Try this -

$this->order_by('title','ASC or DESC or RANDOM');

Comment: if I use 'ASC' or 'DESC' product display page 1 same with next page, but if use 'Random' between page 1 and next page different product display